# Define base64 data as some kind of variable to use it in stylesheet

Tags: css, variables, base64

In css (and as far as I know, everywhere else, even in address string) it is possible to specify an image in base64 form like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAGHRFWHRBdXRob3IAbWluZWNyYWZ0aW5mby5jb23fZidLAAAAk0lEQVQ4y2P4//8/AyUYwcAD+OzN/oMwshjRBoA0Gr8+DcbIhhBlAEyz+qZZ/7WPryHNAGTNMOxpJvo/w0/uP0kGgGwGaZbrKgfTGnLc/0nyAgiDbEY2BCRGdCDCnA2yGeYVog0Aae5MV4c7Gzk6CRqAbDM2w/EaQEgzXgPQnU2SAcTYjNMAYm3GaQCxNuM0gFwMAPUKd8XyBVDcAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

In my project I use an image several times in different places of a single css file. Currently on stage of development I use LESS to store an image in variable, then compile the  to CSS.

**The main question is: is it possible with css only to specify base64 as some kind of internal name (URI maybe, idk) only once to use it in whole stylesheet somewhere by that name?** *(Like we do with external fonts loaded to css - we specify url only once and name it, then we use the font with the name we gave it)*

What I really need is to be able to specify that data in CSS only once with some "buts" (read below)

Say, do something like this:

```
@data{
 data-name: anAxe;
 src: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAGHRFWHRBdXRob3IAbWluZWNyYWZ0aW5mby5jb23fZidLAAAAk0lEQVQ4y2P4//8/AyUYwcAD+OzN/oMwshjRBoA0Gr8+DcbIhhBlAEyz+qZZ/7WPryHNAGTNMOxpJvo/w0/uP0kGgGwGaZbrKgfTGnLc/0nyAgiDbEY2BCRGdCDCnA2yGeYVog0Aae5MV4c7Gzk6CRqAbDM2w/EaQEgzXgPQnU2SAcTYjNMAYm3GaQCxNuM0gFwMAPUKd8XyBVDcAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
}
```

And then

```
.axeButton{
 background: 'anAxe';
}
```

I could just define background for multiple classes but that's not an option due to some reasons. Also I could use clientside LESS but it's not an option either.

Is there any options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in CSS but, you could place that data URI in a global file like a header or footer and re-use it using JavaScript, if that's an option.

Alternatively, you could group selectors in CSS like

```
#a, .b.c, #c d { data URI goes here .. }
```

Comment: well yes, that's kinda much like what I do now for css.